# sudden failure of \ref recognising \label

Tags: labels

PROBLEM NOW SOLVED, many thanks for help.

In fact, for years I have been using 'alt command T' to typeset, now find that if I click on 'typeset' button it all works.

Not sure why the old method has stopped working, same issue on my latop using much older version. Think this may remain one of life's mysteries.

Crossreferencing using `\label` and `\ref` has suddenly stopped working. I am using `TexShop` on an iMac.

I have constructed this simple file to see if I can track down the problem:

```
%
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 %
\begin{document}
%  Environments
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}[section]
%
%
\section{Trial}\label{TRIALsec}
Trying labels
\begin{Def}\label{hallo}
HALLO
\end{Def}
%
Definition \ref{hallo}
%
\section{More}
The previous section \ref{TRIALsec}
%
 \end{document}
%
```

When I compile the file the`.aux`-file contains what I believe are the correct labels

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Trial}{1}}
\newlabel{TRIALsec}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{hallo}{{1.1}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}More}{1}}
```

but these error messages appear:

> LaTeX Warning: Reference `hallo' on page 1 undefined on input line 15.
>
> LaTeX Warning: Reference `TRIALsec' on page 1 undefined on input line 18.

I have compiled a dozen or so times, and simply cannot get the `\ref` command to generate the actual numbers in the `.pdf`, even though they are there in the `.aux`-file.

I have been using `LateX` for decades, and have files which used to compile correctly and now do not do so.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!. I get the same `.aux` file, but no error message.

Comment: is it possible that the `.aux` file is being deleted before the latex job is restarted?  (check in the log file to see;   there should be a record, either showing that yes, it was read, or that it was not found.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The `.log` file also shows, whether the correct `.aux` file is read or a file from another location.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved with an unspecified method

Comment: According to the menu entry description, COMMAND-ALT-T does “Trash Aux & Typeset”, which clearly will reproduce the issue, because the .aux file is deleted before typesetting, so no cross reference can be solved. The correct keyboard action is COMMAND-T.